# Hibernate - Does the resulting SQL from a HQL query get cached by the hibernate system?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

Hibernate 3.3

If I've got code that is dynamically creating hibernate hql queries like

```
String query = "from Foo where ";
if( beforeDate != null ) then query+=" createdBefore < :before";
session.createQuery(query);
```

Does the resulting sql that will get executed on the db get cached by the SessionManager so that if the same query keeps getting executed it won't have to get recompiled everytime or will it get re-parsed and rebuilt by hibernate every time?

I'm thinking that to increase performance of my db code I'll have to write some static named queries in hibernate to reduce the parsing overhead if there is some.

Comment: sql is generated each time. The query is not parsed 2nd time in the same session (provided you use the same result of createQuery(query))

Comment: Ah that would be the rub, I think that we are, so basically your saying that everytime createQuery is called, it's re-parsed correct?  If so that we should probably change our pattern.

Comment: no, if use named query, the string is not parsed, yet sql is to be generated. I am almost positive about the generation of the SQL, but I might need to check the source. I dont use queries myself but criteria.

Comment: as tdavies points out, the major cause for slow down should be the database execution, not the query process time in hibernate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SQL won't be cached, because you are creating a new Query each time. You could cache the Query, but I doubt that the parsing overhead is significant.

Some things to check for performance of that query:

- Do you have a suitable index on `createdBefore`?
- Are the relationships which `Foo` has with other objects 'appropriate' -- that is are they lazy if possible and strict if necessary. Say `Foo` has a member which is loaded from the `Bar` table. If you make the relationship lazy, you avoid a join, but if you then access the `Bar` belonging to each `Foo` you've done `n` more queries, and would have been better off setting `lazy="false"`.
- If you make the query many times with the same value for `before`, and the Foo table is only updated via Hibernate, and it is not updated more often than it is queried, and the size of the result sets is not too large, you could use the [query cache](http://tech.puredanger.com/2009/07/10/hibernate-query-cache/)

As always with any performance issue, make sure you have repeatable before and after measurements.

Comment: "The SQL won't be cached, because you are creating a new Query each time" - you are wrong! Hibernate creates SQLQueryPlan object for each sql query. Hibernate always use same SQLQueryPlan object then you invoke "createQuery" method for the same sql query twice or more times.